# How to test slack integration in Rails + Active Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, slack-api, rails-activejob

I am using Rails Active Job to queue the slack notification. The scheduler is sidekiq. Everything is working fine but did not get any idea how to write tests for Rails Active Job. I am using [slack-notifier](https://github.com/stevenosloan/slack-notifier) gem to connect with Slack using its web hooks.

In `user.rb`

```
def send_slack!
  text = "New user #{first_name} #{last_name} has signed up"
  channel = "#pltf_signup"
  webhook_url = ENV["SLACK_SIGNUP_WEBHOOK_URL"]

  NotifiableSlackJob.perform_later(webhook_url: webhook_url, text: text, channel: channel) if Rails.env.production?
end
```

In `notifiable_slack_job.rb`

```
class NotifiableSlackJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default 

  def perform(webhook_url:, text:, username: "BOT", channel:, icon_emoji: ":smile_cat:")
    notifier = Slack::Notifier.new webhook_url, username: username, channel: channel, icon_emoji: icon_emoji
    notifier.ping text
  end
end
```

Tests I have written so far is on `notifiable_slack_job_spec.rb`

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe NotifiableSlackJob, type: :job do
  describe "#perform" do
    it "sends a Slack message" do      
      NotifiableSlackJob.perform_now(webhook_url: ENV["SLACK_SIGNUP_WEBHOOK_URL"], text: "Hi", channel: '#pltf_signup')
    end
  end
end
```

Testing framework I have used is RSpec.
Thank you.

Comment: this [link](https://gist.github.com/ChuckJHardy/10f54fc567ba3bd4d6f1) could be useful for you. There are examples of ActiveJob test.